# How can I turn all rewrite x.php into x.css in a specific directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite all the files in a directory and essentially make their extentions css instead of php. I want to do with with a .htaccess file within that specific directory.

What is the correct method of doing so and are there any special PHP headers I need to set the ensure the file is read as a .css file correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you rather want requests of `*.css` to be rewritten internaly to `*.php`. So try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(foo/.*)\.css$ $1.php [L]
```

While `foo` is here the specific directory.

You now should explicitly declare the output as `text/css` using the following at the begin of the PHP script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/css;charset=<your charset>');
```

Replace `<your charset>` by whatever charset/encoding you are using (probably `ISO-8859-1` or `UTF-8`).

Comment: lol, I didn't see that header mark when I wrote my answer. /me must be blind :P

Comment: The htaccess code wont work. I fixed the spelling mistake. Still get internal server error

Comment: There should be. Well without knowing the error we probably just can guess what the error might be. Have you tried an easier rule to see if mod_rewrite is working? Something like “RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [R]”.

Comment: [Fri Feb 27 23:06:57 2009] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] Z:/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Oh dear, looks like mod_rewrite is not available on your Apache install. That's going to limit your possibilities a bit. You could still have URLs like “http://www.example.com/style.php/stylesheetname.css” by looking at PATH_INFO in the PHP script.

Comment: Im running it on my local machine, I could reinstall it or what not?

Comment: Look into your httpd.conf file for a line that starts with “#LoadModule rewrite_module …”, remove the “#” and restart your Apache.

Comment: You win a million jelly beans.

Answer (score 0):

well they don't need a css extension if your just using them from with in your site. They just need to output the header Content-Type: text/css before rendering (I assume) the generated css. Similar sort of thing applies to other file types, if you have a php script that generates an image, you'd do it the same way, except you change the content type to image/png or jpeg or whatever.

However, if you want the outside would to see these generated css files as files with a css extension then mix what I've said with what Gumbo said.